# Google Sheets - How to get headers of all columns where the certain row has TRUE value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry this question might seem easy but I can't get it to work.
How do I get headers of all columns where the certain row has TRUE value? And vice versa.

In other words, referring to an attached image of example table, how do I get the list of all subjects that Jim chose, and how do I get a list of students who chose math?

[table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9rCV.png)

I tried to apply some INDEX/MATCH and FILTER formulas, but did not crack the puzzle. Please, help. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You can apply this formula to get the headers for each row when there is a matching condition. Now if the list you want is a string(like in my example) you will have to drag the formula down for each row since the JOIN/TEXTJOIN function won't work on a bigger range.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(B2:F2=1,$B$1:$F$1, "")))
```

If you just need to get the list in an array and manipulate it later, you can actually return the all the matching array using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:F=1,$B$1:$F$1, ""))
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach works and I did not even think about ARRAYFORMULA function. Second option is better for me as the output is easily manipulated.